# SpringBoot Security fallo hasRole() y hasAuthority()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-security

Quiero que los bloques html que especifico a continuación se muestren u oculten basándonos en el Rol que acceda a la plataforma.

Pongo el código, con las diferentes posibilidades que plantee:

Tengo el siguiente codigo en html con SpringBootSecurity versión 5:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('write_user')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

Estableciendo una autoridad me funciona, pero como es un bloque al que solo van a acceder los admin, me gustaría que fuera por rol:

Sin prefijo:

```
 <li  sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

Con prefijo:

```
<li  sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

Por lo que leí en esta nueva versión ya se usa directamente con hasAuthority y el Rol, pero así tampoco me funciona:

```
  <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')" class="nav-item menu-closed" >
```

El html contiene:

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

Mi clase user:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
   // @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column
    //@NotBlank
    private String username;

    @Column
  //  @NotBlank
    private String surnames;


    @Column
    private String password;

    @Transient
   // @NotBlank
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Column(unique = true)
    //@NotBlank
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String profilePicture;

    @Transient
   // @NotBlank
    private String confirmEmail;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"))
    private Set<Team> team;


    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Role> roles;


    @Transient
    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream()
                .map(Role::getAuthorities)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .map(authority -> {
                    return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getPermission());
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp deletedDate;


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return this.accountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return this.accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return this.credentialsNonExpired;
    }


    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;

    @Builder.Default
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        this.password = null;
    }
```